# IE11 Missing Table Borders In Print Preview

Tags: internet-explorer

http://hurdevan.com/files/test.html

I create custom report cards for schools. We have hundreds these reports and when printed in IE11(or 10) then the table borders disappear if the browser has to page break in the table.

The height of the report is very dynamic and depends on how long each teachers comments are. If the report extends beyond the limits of the page and set margins then the borders disappear.

The only solution I have found is to split the table at the page break point. However, this only works for a few reports as the page break point is hardly at the same place for every student printed.

Is this simply an IE bug or bad programming?